# All the modals on page open together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im studying react and I got a problem. I have a page with pictures from json file. There are modals that should show every full picture I click on, but when I click on every picture, all the modals open together. How can I fix it?

My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

export default function Portfolio() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ persons: [] });
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/portfolio-data.json").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      setState({ persons });
    });
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
        {state.persons.map((person) => (
          <>
            <Card
              style={{ width: "18rem" }}
              className="portfolio-card"
              onClick={handleShow}
            >
              <Card.Img variant="top" src={person.src} className="card-pic" />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{person.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{person.desc}</Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>{person.title}</Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <Image src={person.src} fluid />
              </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: All of the modals use the same state variable "show". You can either break this and have a separate component for each person's card and modal (so that each component has its own state variable) or store the index of the person [.map((person, index)=>...)] in show.

Comment: @Hani thank you very much, it really helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening every Modal since the `show` prop it's scoped on top the component and it is pass to every modal. You could encapsulate the person inside his own component and handle the state over there.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

const Person = ({ person }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  return (
    <>
      <Card
        style={{ width: "18rem" }}
        className="portfolio-card"
        onClick={handleShow}
      >
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={person.src} className="card-pic" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{person.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{person.desc}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>{person.title}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Image src={person.src} fluid />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default function Portfolio() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ persons: [] });
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/portfolio-data.json").then((res) => {
      const persons = res.data;
      setState({ persons });
    });
  }, [setState]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="portfolio-wrapper">
        {state.persons.map((person, index) => (
          <Person person={person} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```